# WF4 refresh workflow designer

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I have succeeded to reestablish the link between two activities after another one ( which existed before between them) was deleted.

```
         if (containerAsFlowchart != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < containerAsFlowchart.Nodes.Count; i++)
            {
                if (containerAsFlowchart.Nodes[i] is FlowStep)
                {
                    FlowStep fs = containerAsFlowchart.Nodes[i] as FlowStep;

                    if (fs.Next == null)
                    {
                        if (i < containerAsFlowchart.Nodes.Count - 1)
                        {
                            fs.Next = (FlowNode)((containerAsFlowchart.Nodes[i + 1] as FlowStep));
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
        }
```

Al works fine till now, but even if the connection is made back, I am not able to visualize it in the workflow designer. If I extend or collapse an activity, or any other operation which refreshes the workflow, that pretty arrow is back there but.. is there any way to do this programmatically, and trigger this repainting straight after I delete one activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the changes to be visible on the designer you've to directly edit its [ModelItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.presentation.model.modelitem.aspx).

```
var modelItem = Designer.Context.Services.GetService<ModelService>().Root;

// Do changes through modelItem ...
```

For example, to change the DisplayName of the root activity:

```
modelItem.Properties["DisplayName"].Value = "New Name";
```

What `ModelItem` does is to keep every part of the workflow in an agnostic model structure, from complex types down to a simple integer. That model is use by the designer itself to print the workflow to the screen among other things (read arguments, variables, etc.).

Use the debugger and watch the model to learn more.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i will start reading on this. On this case though ,i've just tried to change the display name. Indeed a ModelChanged event is raised but the designer layout is not updated. From what i've seen, it updates when i navigate the tree, or .. to be more concise, when i expand and collapse the flowcharts..

Comment: OK, i got it, thank you very much again. I misunderstood what you told me. That works perfectly. I get the ModelItem for my FowStep and call .Properties["Next"].SetValue(((FlowNode)((containerAsFlowchart.Nodes[i + 1] as FlowStep))); Maybe i ask a bit too much but i have one more question . I am getting that model item with some difficulties. I am first searching with ModelService.Find and get all the FlowSteps in the workflow designer, and only after i am iterating over that collection and search for a matching name. .. is there a simpler way ?